# Import cannot be resolved for java cucumber eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

I made a new project in eclipse.
java version I have is  "11.0.10" 2021-01-19 LTS
Eclipse version is 4.19.0

this is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>practice_test</groupId>
  <artifactId>practice_test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>practice_test</name>
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.10.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>6.10.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now the import for Given,When,Then commands are not resoolved
and import for Webdriver not resolved.
what should I change please

Answer (score 0):

Check if your IDE is able to download it. look for the m2 folder and verify that the pom and the jar are there.
If they is not there, delete the 6.10.4 folder and do a maven update, or if you want just delete the content and download them from here.

[**Maven repository cucumber-java**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java/6.10.4)